# Cheerio get nested child element text

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, web-scraping, cheerio

I am new to html/css.

I am trying to loop through each div of search results and filter out those with certain text (but the texts are deeply nested).

This is how I do it. I loaded the whole html. I am trying to get an array elements based on selectors. This is done by:

```
const elements = $(
      "div.results.row > div[data-attr]",
    );
```

and that gives me a list of `div` results with the attribute `data-attr` (with or without values set) in it.

However, based on the array of result, I need to further get the text in one of the elements in it as well. Example of a result element:

```
<div data-attr="some random attrib here for each element">
  <span>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>
          <span class="unique class name here but same for all">some deep child text i need to extract</span>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

This is how my current code works:

```
const remainingElements = elements.filter((_, element) => {
      return !!element.attribs["data-attr"];
    });
```

It returns me the list with actual values inside `data-attr` (some elements dont have values in it, so I had to filter those away).

However as mentioned I need to get the text, so I can further filter out results with certain text.

I tried this but I get empty string:

```
const remainingElements = elements.filter((_, element) => {
console.log(
        $(element)
        .children(".unique.class.name.here.but.same.for.all")
        .text(),
      );
      return !!element.attribs["data-attr"];
    });
```

So how can I use selector on existing element? Or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Filter divs with certain text like this?

```
$("div.results.row > div[data-attr]").get().filter(el => !$(el).text().match(/not me!/))
```